# Horizontal scrolling buttons for mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have developed a web solution which uses [mousewheel js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) in order to apply horizontal scrolling. You can view the web site's page here. DEMP REMOVED

As you can see, i'm trying to simulate a mouse scroll on a click of a button, Currently i'm using this jquery snippet

```
var scrolled=0;
$("#btnRight").on("click" ,function(){
   scrolled=scrolled+300;
   $('html, body, *').scrollRight(scrolled);
});

var scrolled=0;
$("#btnLeft").on("click" ,function(){
   scrolled=scrolled+300;
   $('html, body, *').scrollLeft(scrolled);
});
```

the moment on these events are triggered, an error is produced.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollRight'

is this due to me targetting the entire body ? or is it not due to targetting a specific div ?
can the experts please be kind to provide me a hint or a elegant solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `scrollRight` function.

Use `scrollLeft` but have `scrolled=scrolled-300` instead

Comment: Thank you but still the error occurs : 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollRight' 

Any idea ?

Comment: You're still using `scrollRight` somewhere. Remove all instances of it and replace with `scrollLeft`